# Render Result doesn't match my background image in Camera View

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, image, scale

So I'm making a movie where I'm compositing my animated characters into a real life scene by compositing them into a picture like Augmented Reality! 
So it's just an image but for some reason the scale and the placement of my characters in the background image in the viewport doesn't match up with the scale of my characters in the Render Result!  I have a mask in this scene and I've added scale nodes after the Alpha over nodes and I've also made sure there's no animation on my camera and the resolution is 100%!!! Anyway it would be awesome if someone could help me! Thank you![image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vwW0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I feel dumb but hopefully this helps someone else!  I had to mess with it for a while because when I just had the render result it wasn't working but actually the scale node fixed it I just had to change the background image to my Render Result!